# How can I triple boot windows 10 with windows 8 and ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, ubuntu-14.04

Before you mark this question as duplicate please read it carefully. I haven't found similar situation like me in superuser. Currently, I have installed windows 8 and ubuntu. It boots using Grub2 in startup I need to select one of them using Grub. Now I want to install windows 10 but the problem is if I install windows 10 then I won't be able to boot to Ubuntu as windows 10 will overwrite grub with its bootloader. Now my question is, how can get all 3 options to choose when I install windows 10? This is different then win7+win10+ubuntu triple boot in the sense that win 10 uses uefi ??

Answer (score 1):

Please be noted that you need a Windows 10 installation disc(and a product key) to install Windows 10.

First, in your Windows 8, launch `Disk management`. In there, resize a disk partition for Windows 10 installation.(It should be at least 20GB). Before installing Windows 10, get an USB stick with Ubuntu installer.

Next, insert Windows 10 installation disc into your computer. Make sure you have changed the boot order. Windows 10 will start to install automatically.  When you are choosing installation type, select Custom (advanced). Select the new empty partition you have created. If you select the wrong partition, data and OS in that partition might be wiped.

Your computer will reboot multiple times. When the installation is completed, shutdown your computer(NOTE: To prevent data lose, you should restart your computer, or disable fast boot. If you choose to restart your computer, plug in the USB which contains Ubuntu before your Windows starts). Hit the power button, plug in the USB and change the boot order. Select "Try Ubuntu Without Installing". Once you are in Ubuntu, open `Terminal` and run `boot-repair`. You're done!